# Android: reset the choice mode of a gridview to default

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I am programmatically showing the `CAB` associated with a `GridView` using the code below:

```
fileDirGridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(gridViewMultiChoiceModeListener);
fileDirGridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
fileDirGridView.setItemChecked(position, true);
```

Now i want to dissociate the `multiChoiceModeListener` and set everything back to the way it was before. To do that i use the following code which always results in a StackOverFull Error.

```
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fileDirGridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);

        }
```

`Logcat`:

```
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875): java.lang.StackOverflowError
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6027)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2562)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.finish(ActionBarImpl.java:846)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1150)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.example.androidfilemanager.MainActivity$7.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:465)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6027)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2562)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.finish(ActionBarImpl.java:846)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1150)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.example.androidfilemanager.MainActivity$7.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:465)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6027)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2562)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.finish(ActionBarImpl.java:846)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1150)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.example.androidfilemanager.MainActivity$7.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:465)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6027)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2562)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.finish(ActionBarImpl.java:846)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1150)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.example.androidfilemanager.MainActivity$7.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:465)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6027)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2562)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.finish(ActionBarImpl.java:846)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1150)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.example.androidfilemanager.MainActivity$7.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:465)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6027)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2562)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.finish(ActionBarImpl.java:846)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1150)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.example.androidfilemanager.MainActivity$7.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:465)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6027)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2562)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.finish(ActionBarImpl.java:846)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1150)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.example.androidfilemanager.MainActivity$7.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:465)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6027)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2562)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.finish(ActionBarImpl.java:846)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1150)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.example.androidfilemanager.MainActivity$7.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:465)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6027)
11-28 07:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(14875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneW
```

Comment: can you post the `logcat`?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare added the logcat to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was setting the `choiceMode` within the `onDestroyActionMode()` which resulted in `stackoverflow` error. So i just started a new thread within the same method and reset the `choiceMode` in there in the thread created.

```
@Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fileDirGridView.clearChoices();
                    fileDirGridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);    
                }
            };

            thread.start();
        }
```